# Scheme function that returns function is returning unexpected value

Tags: scheme, return, r5rs

I have a function in scheme

```
    (define (m-m f)
      (let ((count 0))
      (define (h-m-c?) count)
      (define (r-c) (begin (set! count 0) count))
      (define (m-f m)
        (cond ((eq? m 'h-m-c?) (h-m-c))
              ((eq? m 'r-c) (r-c))
              (else (set! count (+ 1 count)) f)))
      m-f))
```

where m-f is a function that is returned.

However, rather than returning a value, it returns

```
    #<procedure:m-f>
```

It appears there is no error with the code, so why doesn't this return a usable value?

Comment: What's wrong with a procedure as a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told it to return `m-f`. That's the name of a procedure that you defined, so it's returning the procedure. To use this return value, you need to assign it to another variable.

```
(define thing1 (m-m 'unused))
(define thing2 (m-m 'who-cares))
(thing1 'h-m-c?)
(thing1 'increment)
(thing1 'h-m-c?)
(thing2 'h-m-c?)
```

Some other commentary:

Procedure names ending in `?` are used for predicates that report true/false.

You don't need `begin` in `(r-c)`. Procedure bodies allow multiple expressions, and execute them in order just like `begin`.

Why didn't you define a function for the case where `count` is incremented, like you did for the other cases?

Using the default for incrementing seems inappropriate, you should require a specific `m` parameter for this.

What's the purpose of the `f` parameter? The only thing it's used for is to be returned when incrementing? Wouldn't the new value of `count` be a more useful return value? It seems like it's intended to be a "name" for the instance; if so, perhaps you should add a new operation to return the name, rather than doing this when incrementing.

EDIT:

Based on the answer below, I suspect you're misusing the `f` parameter. It's probably supposed to be a function that you call when doing the increment.  So you need to supply it as a lambda expression, and return `(f)` rather than just `f`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I'm new to scheme.  I was using the procedure the wrong way.  Thanks also for your tips.  This procedure counts the number of times another procedure is called, so it takes a procedure as an argument.  For example, giving these calls to the m-m:(define m-m (make-monitored (sqrt 100)))
;(m-m 'reset-count)
;(m-m (sqrt 100))
;(m-m 'how-many-calls?)  Again, thanks for your tips!